# How to accelerate minterpolate in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using minterpolate of ffmpeg(version git-2020-08-21) with this command on Windows 10:

```
ffmpeg -i $file -filter:v "minterpolate=mi_mode=mci:me_mode=bidir:mc_mode=aobmc:vsbmc=1:fps=60" -c:a copy "$file_60fps.mp4"
```

But the CPU load is only about `15%` to `20%` while working.

My CPU is AMD 4800H with 8 cores and 16 threads. And I have a NVIDIA GTX1650 with CUDA.

I cannot find any document about GPU acceleration or multithread methods of minterpolate.

Have tried `-threads 16` but nothing changed.

How to accelerate the process?

Comment: Bit of guesswork from a Mac user looking for a parallel to Acitivity Monitor… Have you looked at the [Utilization View](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/utilization-view?view=vs-2019) to see if all cores are being properly utilised? [idk how ffmpeg might use GPU acceleration] *(oh, that might be for VS only - I was looking for something that would just show you individual core usage, which is easy to see on a Mac)*

Comment: There is no GPU version of the minterpolate filter.

Comment: @llogan I guess it's true... Now that minterpolate cannot fully utilize a CPU or GPU, I'm also looking for an alternative tool

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **Linux/MacOS hack:**

Use a bash script that creates slices of the main video, runs parallel `minterpolate` instances on the slices, and then concatenates the resulting "minterpolated" slices together.

Here's a sample: 
https://gist.github.com/majal/1e63a511b41faeae188083777f8e4b46

(For Windows, <strike>move to Linux</strike> someone has to make a batch file like this.)

As expected, it could **get a bit funny** on the concatenation points.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution, there's also preliminary work on using Tensorflow to slow down video, and TF uses GPU.

See for example, TF cuda:

https://github.com/Riccorl/Super-SloMo-tf2

or a pytorch implementation

https://github.com/avinashpaliwal/Super-SloMo

Adding one frame is decent for me but starts to go rapidly downwards, jerky.

https://youtu.be/Klu-cS81g0k

Answer (score 0):

For your workload, there are two potential solutions:

**1. FFmpeg's `libplacebo` filter integration:**

The platform-agnostic [`libplacebo` project](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libplacebo) may be a better fit for the interplolation mode(s) you're looking for, integrated in FFmpeg as a GPU-accelerated [filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#libplacebo).
It's dependency is a Vulkan implementation with a fallback to `llvm` if needed. This can be toggled on via `-init_hw_device vulkan:llvmpipe` in FFmpeg on systems with LLVM installed AND no need to run this on a discrete GPU.

As [currently documented](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Scaling), libplacebo's `frame_mixer` private option has multiple kernels that can be selected at runtime, based on the desired temporal frame mixing mode:

**(a). none:** Disables frame mixing, giving a result equivalent to "nearest neighbour" semantics. This is the default.

**(b).oversample:** This kernel oversamples the input video to create a "Smooth Motion"-type effect: if an output frame would exactly fall on the transition between two video frames, it is blended according to the relative overlap. This is the recommended option whenever preserving the original subjective appearance is desired.

**(c). mitchell_clamp:** This is a larger filter kernel that smoothly interpolates multiple frames in a manner designed to eliminate ringing and other artefacts as much as possible. This is the recommended option wherever maximum visual smoothness is desired. It's also the most compute-intensive mode.

**(d)linear:** Linear blend/fade between frames. Especially useful for constructing e.g. slideshows.

All Interpolation operations require that the private filter option `fps` be set to the desired output frame rate. This value can be rational, e.g. 60000/1001 (59.97fps) and 30000/1001 (for NTSC's 29.97fps) or a decimal value, eg 30, etc.  With the `fps` option set, input video frames will then be interpolated to rescale the video to the specified target framerate as governed by the aforementioned `frame_mixer` option.

A trivial example is provided below demonstrating the use of the `mitchell_clamp` temporal frame mixing mode with VFR input to smoothed constant 60 fps output:

```sh
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "input" \
-init_hw_device vulkan \
-vf "libplacebo=fps=60:frame_mixer=mitchell_clamp" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 "output.mkv"
```

In my testing, it's a very performant filter, allowing for real-time throughput with [multiple 1:N transcoding workflows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55747785/4675388) on both [Intel's OneVPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76128676/4675388) and [NVIDIA's NVENC](https://superuser.com/a/1650962/473795) encoder wrappers.

**2. Intel's `vpp_qsv` filter implementation:**

The second option is strictly tied to Intel's [OneVPL](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/vpl/overview.html#gs.169xnk) and [(the currently discontinued) QuickSync](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK)-capable systems running a supported Intel GPU. In this case, and with a current FFmpeg build, you may use the `vpp_qsv` filter. It has a private `framerate` option with similar arguments to `libplacebo`'s private `fps` option.

You may print out the filter's usage options via:

```sh
ffmpeg -h filter=vpp_qsv
```

With Intel, the interpolation modes available are dependent on the specific runtime(s) selected in the FFmpeg build, and as such, performance and conformance are very dependent on BOTH the runtime in use (legacy QSV vs modern OneVPL) and the GPU in use. See [this issue](https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK/issues/2065) for more on this application notice.

**Disclaimer:**

Your mileage may vary, depending on your input file characteristics,the selected encoder wrapper(s) in use and the target interpolation requirements that may differ from what `libplacebo` and `vpp_qsv` filters can cover. Test coverage for this is recommended before deciding on whether switching away from `minterpolate` covers your specific requirements.